# /MP doesn't enable OpenMP support in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, openmp

I have this code in visual c++ 2012:

```
void Run()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int imageNo=0;imageNo<4;imageNo++)
    {
        RunForOneImage(imageNo, Data[imageNo],
                       width, height,
                       OutputWidth, OutputHeight);  
    }
}
```

All variables in `RunForOneImage` are local variables and it doesn't use any global or class member variables.

When  run it, I can see that only one core became busy and other core are idle.

Why this is not running in parallel?

I selected multi processor option in visual studio  (/MP). Is there any other option that I should select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`/MP`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb385193.aspx) option means that ***the compilation*** will run on multiple processors, it's purpose is to *"reduce the total time to compile the source files"*.

It has nothing to do with **OpenMP API**. To enable OpenMP support, there's an [`/openmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw509c3b.aspx) option (in the documentation you'll also find an example and the description of how to enable OpenMP support).

Answer (score 2):

Just go to Project Properties->C/C++->Language->Open MP Support and switch it to Yes.